# Multiple for commands in batch

Tags: for-loop

I am having some issues with the FOR command.  Ive read countless articles on here and nothing hits exactly what i am looking for.  I am trying to take a directory with a lot of files (about 6000) , read the files and format that data into a single file if the variables read 1 not 0.  The script is far from complete i just have an issue.  The code i have so far is as such

```
@echo off

set Rfile=
dir /b g:\health\test\ >> dir.txt
For /F "tokens=1 delims=" %%y in (dir.txt) do Call :Read %%y

:Read

set Rfile=%~1

For /F "tokens=1,2,3,4,5,6 delims=" %%a in (g:\health\test\%Rfile%) do Call :test %%a

:test
SET Machine=%~1
SET BSOD=%~2
SET NTFS=%~3
SET DISK=%~4
Set Workstation=%~5
Set Server=%~6


If NOT "%BSOD%" == "%Machine%" (

echo %machine% %BSOD% %NTFS% %DISK% %WorkStation% %Server%

 )

:EOF
```

This gives me output as such from a file that that has the information below.

> COMPUTER BSOD0 NTFS0 DISK0 Service0 Service0

test" No space but test is on the line below the rest of the output

I do not want the file name (in this case test) in the output.  What am i doing wrong here?

> File information "COMPUTER BSOD0 NTFS0 DISK0 Service0 Service0"

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that your FOR loop is calling `:test` as expected but, once you have finished with your FOR loop, you are dropping through into `:test` anyway. If you do this, then %1 will be the input into your script (`test` in this case).

To fix, simply add a `GOTO :eof` as so:

```
For /F "tokens=1,2,3,4,5,6 delims=" %%a in (g:\health\test\%Rfile%) do Call :test %%a

REM Do not fall through into the :test label code!
GOTO :eof

:test
SET Machine=%~1
```

As an aside, you should not have a label called `:EOF`. There is an implicit `eof` label already defined.

As a second aside, you should ensure that all your subroutines end in `goto :eof` as well. You only have 1 subroutine (`:test`) in this example, so it works fine, but if you add more you will have problems.

Comment: Thank you works great too early in the morning and rusty on my batch.